# My next loop doesn't start

Tags: php, html, for-loop

I try to make a function that creates some triangles.

```
<pre>
<?php
$angka = isset($_POST['angka']) ? $_POST['angka'] : "0";
if ($angka)
{
  $segitiga = "";
  $max = $angka + $angka - 1;
  $ctr = 0;
  for ($i=1; $i<=$angka; $i++){
    echo $i;
    for ($j=1;$j<=$max;$j++){
      if ($i = $j){
      if($j<=$angka){
        $ctr++;
      }elseif($j>$angka){
        $ctr--;
      }
        echo " ". $ctr * $ctr;
      }else{
        echo " ";
      }
    }
    echo ""."<br>";
  }
}
?>
</pre>
```

The line of `for ($i=1; $i<=$angka; $i++)` is stop. It just run it once.

The next `$i` is not running. There is no next `$i`.

Actually, I want to make it as a function it, but this still doesn't work.

Comment: what is the value of `$angka`?

Comment: Clean up your code.  Remove code that is commented out, and provide the details such as the value of `$angka` so we can help.

Comment: it works now, the culprit is  'if ($i = $j)' it should be  'if ($i == $j)' like Brian Putt said.
now i can continue my code.

Comment: that's only part of the problem, look at my answer for the other part

Comment: You have your loop starting at 1 and possibly stopping at 0 !!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this may be the culprit

```
if ($i = $j){
```

It should be

```
if ($i == $j){
```

Because you're setting `$i` to `$j` which if `$angka` is 1, it will exit the for loop since it's `$i <=$angka`

Comment: thanks a lot man.
just starting using php again, really a lot to learn.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i=1; $i<=$angka; $i++){
```

your $i start at 1 and stops where it is equal to $angka
where $angka could be 0 because of

```
$angka = isset($_POST['angka']) ? $_POST['angka'] : "0";
```

so that loop may never execute , not even once
if you want to test what I'm saying, I'm executing your code with `$angka` set manually and it runs normally 
here is the [output](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/1asp-6rcq) for the following code

```
$angka =  "3";
echo "<pre>";

if ($angka)
{
    $segitiga = "";
    $max = $angka + $angka - 1;
    $ctr = 0;

    for ($i=1; $i<=$angka; $i++){
        echo $i;
        echo 'the i loop here'.PHP_EOL;
        for ($j=1;$j<=$max;$j++){
            echo 'the j loop here'.PHP_EOL;
            if ($i == $j){
                if($j<=$angka){
                    $ctr++;              
                }elseif($j>$angka){
                    $ctr--;
                }
                echo " ". $ctr * $ctr;
            }else{
                echo " ";
            }
        }
        echo ""."<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: I already try with a input number greater than 1.
But the problem is solved now, thank you for your advice.
I should've mention the input is greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed code:

```
<?php
$angka = isset($_POST['angka']) ? $_POST['angka'] : "0";
if ($angka)
{
    $segitiga = "";
    $max = $angka + $angka - 1;
    $ctr = 0;

    for ($i=1; $i<=$angka; $i++){
      echo $i;
      ///*
      for ($j=1;$j<=$max;$j++){
        if ($i == $j){ //NOTICE how this needs to be `==` and not `=`
            if($j<=$angka){
              $ctr++;
            }elseif($j>$angka){
              $ctr--;
            }
            //$segitiga = $segitiga . ($ctr * $ctr);
            echo " ". $ctr * $ctr;
        }else{
            //$segitiga = $segitiga . " ";
            echo " ";
        }
      }
      //*/
      //$segitiga = $segitiga . "\n";

        echo ""."<br>";
    }
    //echo $segitiga;
}
?>
```